# Magento 2.1 set group ID on a custom registration form

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-group

I have a custom phtml file that contains a copy of the customer registration form in my Magento 2.1 site.  Now in this form I have

```
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" id="group_id" value="3" />
```

I also created a file located in app/code/Magento/Customer/Model called CustomerExtractor.php and the contents of the file is below but now when I creat a test customer using the new registration for the user is not assigned to the group_id that is set in the form?

```
<?php
   /**
     *
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
      namespace Magento\Customer\Model;
      use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
      use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
      use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupManagementInterface;
      use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
      class CustomerExtractor
      {
       /**
         * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory
         */
        protected $formFactory;
        /**
          * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory
          */
        protected $customerFactory;
       /**
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         */
        protected $storeManager;
        /**
          * @var GroupManagementInterface
          */
        protected $customerGroupManagement;
        /**
          * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper
          */
        protected $dataObjectHelper;
        /**
          * @param Metadata\FormFactory $formFactory
          * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory 
        $customerFactory
          * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
          * @param GroupManagementInterface $customerGroupManagement
          * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
        */
        public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    GroupManagementInterface $customerGroupManagement,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
) {
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->customerGroupManagement = $customerGroupManagement;
    $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
}
/**
 * @param string $formCode
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 * @param array $attributeValues
 * @return CustomerInterface
 */
public function extract(
    $formCode,
    RequestInterface $request,
    array $attributeValues = []
) {
    $customerForm = $this->formFactory->create(
        CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
        $formCode,
        $attributeValues
    );
    $customerData = $customerForm->extractData($request);
    $customerData = $customerForm->compactData($customerData);
    $allowedAttributes = $customerForm->getAllowedAttributes();
    $isGroupIdAllow = isset($allowedAttributes['group_id']);
    $customerDataObject = $this->customerFactory->create();
    $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
        $customerDataObject,
        $customerData,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface::class
    );
    $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
    if (!$isGroupIdAllow || ($isGroupIdAllow &&(is_null($customerDataObject->getGroupId()))) ) {
        $customerDataObject->setGroupId(
            $this->customerGroupManagement->getDefaultGroup($store->getId())->getId()
        );
    }
    $customerDataObject->setWebsiteId($store->getWebsiteId());
    $customerDataObject->setStoreId($store->getId());
    return $customerDataObject;
}
```

}

Comment: Hey, is issue fixed?

Comment: No I am still not able to figure out how to get this issue resolved. I even set a bounty to try to get more people into this thread but that did not work.

Comment: @user1739740 Do you want to have all registered customers in customer_group_id=3? if so, this can be easily accomplished by an observer.'

Answer (score 4):

This is not the only issue in Magento  **Custom registration form** , also the issue exists in  **Default registration form**.If we passing any group_id from default registration form then that customer group does not set for that customer it always takes store default group_id
For in case of *default registration form*  Issue in [Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor] c(https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L92) class.
Even , i enabled attribute  **group_id** in customer registration form using

`INSERT INTO`customer_form_attribute`(`form_code`,`attribute_id`) VALUES ('customer_account_creat', '10');`

But still is does not work bcoz...

Logic issue in   [if ($isGroupIdEmpty) {](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L92)

Means,
 instead of enabling **group_id**   for customer registration form and sending this field   value from , Magento **forcefully set Customer group as the default group .**

That is the problem.

### Solution:

Solution  is that, we need to modify condition

1. don't execute [$customerDataObject->setGroupId(](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L93) when **_group_id_** is enable for  registration form
2. execute  [$customerDataObject->setGroupId(](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L93)  when  **_group_id_** is  **not enable for  registration form**
3. execute  [$customerDataObject->setGroupId(](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L93)  when  **_group_id_** is  **enable for  registration form *  but group id **does not selected** from form

So. my suggestion change `if ($isGroupIdEmpty) {`

to

`if (!$isGroupIdAllow || ($isGroupIdAllow &&(is_null($customerDataObject->getGroupId()))) ) {
            $customerDataObject->setGroupId(
                $this->customerGroupManagement->getDefaultGroup($store->getId())->getId()
            );
        }`

Also for use developer perspective change variable name
[$isGroupIdEmpty](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L83)

to

`isGroupIdAllow`

Comment: thanks for the comments. So in which file and what path to the file and I changing the if ($isGroupIdEmpty) { line in?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/CustomerExtractor.php#L83

Comment: So I created a the directrory /Magento/Customer/Model in the app/code directory. Now I created the file CustomerExtractor.php and put the contents  in there from the github. and changed by !$isGroupIdAllow section but when I create a customer from my custom  for where I have a hidden field setting the group_id it still does not work the customer is created by assigned to the default group ?

Comment: I am still looking for guidance on this.

Comment: i will do at today

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure  exactly that you need.
This solution will add customer group select to registration form.
1. In template `form/register.phtml` in fieldset add :

```
    <div class="field customer-groups required">
        <label for="customer-group" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Customer Group') ?></span></label>
        <select name="customer_group" id="customer-group" data-validate="{required:true}">
            <option value=""><?php echo __('Customer Group') ?></option>
            <?php foreach ($block->getCustomerGroups() as $customerGroup) : ?>
                <option
                    value="<?php echo $customerGroup->getId(); ?>"
                    <?php echo ($customerGroup->getId()==$block->getFormData()->getCustomerGroup())? 'selected' : ""; ?>><?php echo $customerGroup->getCode(); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

In block  add function `getCustomerGroups` :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data $directoryHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config $configCacheType,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\CollectionFactory $regionCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection $customerGroupCollection,
    $data = []
)
{
    $this->customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;
    parent::__construct($context, $directoryHelper, $jsonEncoder, $configCacheType, $regionCollectionFactory,
        $countryCollectionFactory, $moduleManager, $customerSession, $customerUrl, $data);
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getCustomerGroups()
{
    $result = [];
    $array = $this->customerGroupCollection->toOptionArray();
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if($item['value'] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        $result[] = $this->createGroupObject($item);
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * @param array $item
 * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject
 */
private function createGroupObject(array $item)
{
    $object = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
    $object->setData('id', $item['value']);
    $object->setData('code', $item['label']);

    return $object;
}
```

Comment: Konrad what is the file path and name of file I would add the "In block function getCustomerGroups  ??

Comment: Konrad what is the file path and name of file I would add the "In block function getCustomerGroups  ??  If I add the code to the CustomerData.php file located in /vendor/magento/module-customer/Block  I get a 500 error

Comment: It should be done in block used by template form/register.phtml. The best way - create new module and rewrite  form/register.phtml and block  Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register - here you should add function getCustomerGroups.